# Unable to redirect https traffic from external IP to loopback interface in Fiddler

Tags: https, fiddler

I'm trying to use Fiddler to capture traffic that comes to my machine on its external ip address, and redirect it to the loopback interface without affecting the host header.

I have added the following to the OnBeforeRequest method:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("MyMachineName")){
   oSession.bypassGateway = true;                 
   oSession["x-overrideHost"] = "localhost";
}
```

This works fine for http traffic: I do indeed see a request to `http://MyMachineName` hit the loopback adaptor with its host header intact.

However, when intercepting https traffic I get the following in the response raw view:

```
fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to auth.time-wise.net failed. System.IO.IOException The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.
```

I have Fiddler configured to capture and decrypt https traffic.

Does anyone know why this problem occurs and how it can be remedied?

**Edit: in response to Eric's request for more information**

Fiddler is running as a proxy (i.e. as standard), listening on port 8888.
The clients are (currently) web browsers on the same machine, and so are automatically using the Fiddler proxy, as they've picked up the change in default proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've left out some important details (e.g. what port is Fiddler running on, and how did you configure the remote client to send its traffic to Fiddler?)

Having said that, you will probably want to change your use of `x-overrideHost` to `x-overrideHostname` such that the port number of the traffic being retargeted is preserved.

Comment: yep - that's it. I needed to replace x-overrideHost with x-overrideHostname. Thanks!

Comment: on reflection this totally makes sense now. The reason for the "unexpected packet format" is that it is trying to handshake https, while having been redirected to a plain old http port.